# OSX Can't clone any repo on Github

Tags: git, github, timeout

OSX. I can't clone any repo on GITHUB, but my git can clone other repos that are not on git.

After googling for about 2 hours, I confirmed that there should be something wrong about my git config. Because

- I'm not behind some firewall for i create a virtual machine and it clone the repo on github sucessfully

I have reinstalled git, which is useless. http proxy is useless.

now the error information is like

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/***.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out

Answer (score 0):

ok. I have made a silly mistake.

because I have changed my hosts file, so the ip of github.com is wrong.